# What am I doing wrong, in following Python program, as I'm getting global queue empty?

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I've written this small dummy program which gets a list input e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then output should be

```
{1:2, 2:4, 3:6, 4:8}
```

When I'm printing the output is

```
{1: 2}
{2: 4}
{3: 6}
{4: 8}
True
True
True
True
{}
```

But somehow the queue is empty.

```
import Queue
import math
import multiprocessing   

out_q = Queue.Queue()

def mp_factorizer(nums):
    global out_q
    def worker(num):
        outdict = {}
        outdict[num] = num * 2
        print outdict
        out_q.put(outdict)

    procs = []
    for num in nums:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(num,))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    resultdict = {}

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        print out_q.empty()
        if not out_q.empty():
            resultdict.update(out_q.get())

    # Wait for all worker processes to finish

    return resultdict

di = mp_factorizer([1, 2, 3, 4])
print di
```

Comment: So why are you not waiting for the other processes to finish first?

Comment: Oh, I'm unable to update the code on stackoverflow. The join should be after the for loop.

Comment: You can just [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a global for the queue object. It is not being shared among the processes. Use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead and pass it in as an argument so it'll be managed:

```
def mp_factorizer(nums):
    out_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def worker(num, out_q):
        outdict = {}
        outdict[num] = num * 2
        print outdict
        out_q.put(outdict)


    procs = []

    for num in nums:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=worker,
                args=(num, out_q)
        )
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    resultdict = {}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if not out_q.empty():
            resultdict.update(out_q.get())

    return resultdict
```

Comment: Actually that was my first approach. It still gives the same output.

Comment: @pnv: are you sure you are trying the code *in this answer* (with the join moved *before* getting the queue objects)? Because I certainly see the output you expect.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I just checked, and it's working. I actually had used join after collecting queue.